# can't execute the sql command (object not imposted on an object instance)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

i can't execute this code:

```
foreach (int n in arealist)
        {
            conne.Open();
            SqlCommand fillcombo = new SqlCommand("select ZONE_Descrizione from ZONE where ZONE_ID='" + n + "'", conne);

            areadesc[n] = fillcombo.ExecuteScalar().ToString();


            conne.Close();

        }
```

i have an object not imposted on an object instance  error and i don't know how solve because i already put the "new sqlcommand" in the code .
Areadesc[] is a string array

Comment: are the integers in area list, really going to match the areadesc, eg are they really 0,1,2,3,4... and not 20382 or something ? where and how is areadesc defined, and arealist..

Comment: My guess is that you're actually getting a `NullReferenceException` on `conne.Open`, but we can't really tell - what is the *exact* error message you're seeing? (My guess is "object not imposted" is a translation...)

Comment: Has 'areadesc' been properly declared and initialised with the right size?

Comment: Is `ZONE_ID` an integer? If so do not quote it (also make it a parameter). Second, if `ExecuteScalar` returns null then you cannot call `ToString()` on it so do a null check, then convert to string if you actually get a value.